# How should I flag a "non-effort-at-all" question in Triage?

Tags: support, review-queues, flags, triage

Sometimes (especially at Triage reviews), I see questions like this one:

> I want to write an app which shows applications send or receive data
>   over internet and which ip address and port they use. How can I write
>   this in python?

I understand this can be considered an "Unsalvageable" one, but when trying to flag it, I'm not so sure what flag it is. My guess was that it can be an "unclear what you are asking?", but since what the OP wants is somehow clear, I also think it would be OK to flag it as "Off Topic > recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource".

I have searched in Meta and the accepted answer to [this similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274645/how-to-deal-with-questions-that-ask-about-complete-basics) seems to go for my second guess. However  that other Meta question address "tutorial-seeking" questions, and also seems that there is some open controversy about it.

EDIT: as pointed out in the comments , there is also [this similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288348/why-does-this-question-have-8-upvotes-and-not-closed) in Meta. I know this kind of questions have to be downvoted and flagged. However, for the particular case of Triage, my question is

**What flag should I raise?** (e.g. for the question above).

EDIT:

As suggested by @gnat and other users, the best thing to do here is mark it as "Too Broad", as previous answers to other related cases had proposed:
[Reviewing some awful questions is just a waste of time, can we have a "no comment" close reason for these?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261858/reviewing-some-awful-questions-is-just-a-waste-of-time-can-we-have-a-no-commen/261859#261859)

Comment: _"However the question address "tutorial-seeking" questions ..."_ Asking for off-site resources is clearly off-topic.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I was referring to the one similar Meta question I found, in this case is clear, I know how to flag tutorial-seeking questions.

Comment: For that question, I would have said Too Broad, as an answer for how to write an app which shows applications that sends or receives data over the internet seems like it would take more than a couple paragraphs. But then, I don't know python...

Comment: ["How much text do you suppose it will take to explain things...?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261859/839601)

Comment: That's awesome, @gnat. I've never seen that one. Saved in the archive

Comment: Pretty much anything with a sentence starting out, *"How can I write this "* is going to be too broad. And that 2nd similar question isn't really a dupe.

Comment: @codeMagic glad you liked it. Note btw that as you have over 3K, another option for questions like asked about here is to copy [custom close reason from this answer at MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215806/165773): "Unclear What Help You Need. Please clarify your specific problem or provide... etc"

Comment: Thank you all! I think that totally  answered my question. Now, should I delete, leave it like this or answer and accept so it can remain as a clearer pointer to that solution?

Comment: if one of other questions you learned about answers your question, you can [pick it and close as explained here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250974/165773). FWIW duplication doesn't necessarily imply deletion, see [Dr. Strangedupe...](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) article at SO blog

Comment: VTC unclear, as there is no issue, just a problem statement.