# Is it acceptable to use "Too broad" as a substitute close reason for zero effort questions?

Tags: discussion

If a question simply asked "I need an efficient way to detect that the numbers in an integer array appear exactly twice." should it be closed as too broad?

https://stackoverflow.com/q/29337568/1493294 basically asks that.  It certainly seems to show little effort as it appears to be a cut and paste from a homework assignment but that is all it's asking.

However, there is nothing about it that seems too broad to me.  It is well defined and solvable. It just makes no attempt to hide that it is homework.

What I read in the help center and on meta indicates such questions should just be down voted.  Yet I keep finding them closed.  Am I missing something?

> Answer well-asked questions
>
> Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which...
>
> - ...are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem.
> - ...solicit opinions rather than facts.
> - ...have already been asked and answered many times before.
> - ...require too much guidance for you to answer in full, or request answers to multiple questions.
> - ...are not about programming as defined in the help center.

I don't see "homework" or "zero effort" in that list.

See:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260909/1493294

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253890/1493294

Gnat claims this question is a dupe of [How should I flag a “non-effort-at-all” question in Triage?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288456/1493294) [duplicate] However this question has no answer nor does it cite anything with authority and is itself a duplicate.  It is conflating the issue of an ignorant OP who would require to much effort to answer and an OP who simply hasn't demonstrated effort.  These are not the same issue.

> I want to write an app which shows applications send or receive data over internet and which ip address and port they use. How can I write this in python?

Now that is a broad question.  It happens to also show very little effort.  That doesn't mean every zero effort question is too broad.  That is faulty logic.

Comment: ["How much text do you suppose it will take to explain things...?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261859/839601)

Comment: @gnat OP never asked what a mouse was.  You're conflating zero effort with a demonstration of ignorance.

Comment: Did you read it?  Quote: "Pick *anything*, it does not matter on crap like this"

Comment: "It is well defined and solvable" - yeah, so well defined that OP doesn't even care if the answer is in C# or Java! So well defined that OP doesn't define any specific problem at all, they just copypaste their homework assignment. I don't see why anybody would have a problem with such a crap question being closed and deleted as fast as possible. And btw, if you are the one who upvoted that heap of crap, please read the hover text of the upvote button a hundred times.

Comment: The "Pick anything" attitude is what I'm taking issue with.  It is horribly unjust and a misleading way to respond.

Comment: @I4mpi StackOverflow is a knowledge base.  It doesn't care about the OP.  Therefore the "research effort" doesn't have to be shown by the OP, just by the question.  The OP can be an idiot and it can still be a good question.  Thinking the other way makes this far to personal.  This isn't a popularity contest.

Comment: Yeah, or the the question can be crap. Which is the case with the given question. How is it in any way useful? How is it expressed in a way that is searchable for people with the same issue (if those even exist, because that seems to be a rather contrived problem)? And "horribly unjust" is just a horrible viewpoint - so in your opinion it would be more just if OP got a high quality answer for copypasting their homework assignment? I personally think it's unjust that the OP wasn't banned from SO yet, because with such a first post it's clear what level of quality is to be expected from them.

Comment: Google search for the keywords: "array value exactly twice" and this question is the number one hit.

Comment: @CandiedOrange also note it's the _only_ result that deals with a "dual array" as defined by OP. I'm rather positive that this is because it's a contrived example problem that nobody ever needs in the real world. All _other_ results deal with more practical problems like finding duplicates in an array, or even the only unique value in an array of duplicated values (those examples are often itself somewhat contrived, but far less so than OPs question).

Comment: @l4mpi Computer Science is a much broader field then you are giving it credit for.

Comment: Look, this problem was created by SE, they removed all reasonable language from the close dialog to respond to this question properly.  In the olden days, this would be very quickly dispatched with "Too localized".  The "do you consider yourself a liar" putdown is a low blow, is one liar worse than an SE employee that created thousands of liars?  The dialog was meant to make you feel stoopid so you'll refrain from using it, SE gets a lot less complaints in the inbox today.  Problem solved but we've got a site with a lot of crap today.  If you don't want to act stoopid then just don't use it.

Comment: @CandiedOrange If you don't have anything more useful to say, you might as well delete your account. That's a non-argument at best and a fallacy at worst. SO is not here to deal with everything that falls under "Computer Science", it's here to deal with _useful, practical, specific programming problems_. IMO the question is neither useful, practical or specific; and nothing you've said so far has presented any evidence to the contrary. And btw, [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) clearly states that this question should _not_ have been asked in this way.

Comment: But if you care for having a place to find help where the right person can even *find* your question then act stoopid in the most illogical way possible.  Pick anything, the further from the truth that you are not allowed to speak the better.

Comment: The more personal you make these arguments the less convinced I am that I should emulate your behavior.  Stackoverflow does not exist so you can pass judgement on people.

Comment: I'm saying you _personally_ fail to present any arguments against closing and deleting this specific quesiton. I've already presented many arguments for deleting it. You are the one that ignored most of those arguments and chose to instead say useless things like "Computer Science is a broad field". So far we've only established that the question seems to be somewhat searchable; this still does not make the question _useful_ or _practical_, which is what a SO question should be. So unless you have any actual arguments, I'm not convinced I should even try to understand your viewpoint.

Comment: And "Stackoverflow does not exist so you can pass judgement on people" is just one more completely useless moral judgement on your part. I'm not juding _people_, I'm judging _the usefulness of the question_, which is IMO exactly zero to anybody but OP (and their classmates with the same assignment).

Comment: @HansPassant what do you mean by "too localized?"

Comment: It used to be the close reason to use when an answer to a question can only ever help one person.  Like this one.  You cannot say that anymore.  You'd have to say something that sounds like "helps too many people", your basic objection.

Comment: @HansPassant The message I'm getting here is you guys want questions like these closed using any excuse you can find.  It doesn't mater to you if the rules say it's fine or if guidance says to just downvote them.  So I'll just ask why?  Why is it so important that the question never gets answered?

Comment: You got a link to a meta post that demonstrates what goes wrong when questions like this are not closed.  A Q+A site just stops being functional when that happens, too much time and effort is wasted on irrelevant crap that doesn't help anybody.  If it is important to you to make just one person feel good instead then vote that way, nobody stops you.

Comment: It's all about quality control. Simply think about what would happen if SO would accept homework dumps like those with open arms - if these questions get _answered_, that alone provides a huge incentive for every lazy stundent (and there are tons of them) to simply dump their CS homework on SO. Even worse, if these get _upvoted_, these people now earn reputation for copypasting. And because any half-decent _answers_ to even the worst questions usually get upvoted, this provides an incentive for _answerers_ who don't care about quality. Swift closure is the best way to prevent all of this.

Comment: The disconnect I'm seeing is that if the OP put effort into the question it wouldn't change the value of the question for anyone else looking for the solution.  In fact that only makes it more localized.  So much as I'd like to see the OP put in more effort I don't see the reason to punish someone searching for the answer.

Comment: The disconnect I'm seeing is that you *are* punishing people that search for an answer by not acting.  The next hundred programmers that arrive at that question and get nothing useful from it.  This Q+A site is just about Qs, not the person that asked it.

Comment: @CandiedOrange if OP puts effort into the question, they are either able to solve it themselves or _might_ arrive at a more useful question, such as an error when accessing the array, or scoping issues, or any other kind of bug. Especially in the case of beginners, the bug will probably be a common issue. That in turn means it's potentially useful, unless of course it's complete nonsensical code or one of the 1.5k duplicates of "what is a NPE".

Comment: @HansPassant if it's just about Q and not the person who put in zero effort why would it matter that it's a cut n paste Q?

Comment: "Zero effort" is just your beef with it.  It doesn't help the next hundred programmers, that's the problem.  Questions that do help other programmers do tend to require more than zero effort, it is fairly inevitable.

Comment: Actually not true.  Any idiot can copy and paste a very good question with no extra effort.  If they couldn't you wouldn't be fighting so many duplicates.  If it's the first time this question shows up on stackoverflow well it's just plainly a good question.

Comment: The universe does not have quite enough genial idiots.  It's fairly inevitable.  Focus your discussion on the problematic Qs that require action, not the ones that got it right by accident.

Comment: After searching around meta and help it seems that stackoverflow is fine with homework questions and while it encourages effort it doesn't require it. So this hold still seems unjustified. You've made passionate arguments about why the quesion shouldn't be allowed but you've not cited anything authoritative that disallows it. I'm left to think there is no valid reason for the hold beyond this being an unpopular question.

Comment: @CandiedOrange as I said above, the tour (which is the very first thing a new user should read) literally says _Don't ask questions you haven't tried to find an answer for_. Not "you will be downvoted", not "it's discouraged", simply _don't ask_. Also, why would it need to be explicitly mentioned somewhere that crap like OPs question is not welcome? You have not given any argument why it should be _kept_, except for some vague notion of it being "unfair" (to whom?). That you don't seem to be able to find one seems like a pretty good reason to delete the question.

Comment: I can see you trying to shift the burden of proof there.  Please leave it where it is.  "questions you haven't tried to find an answer for" != "show effort".  After searching around meta it's easy to find evidence that many others feel that while homework questions and no effort questions are unpopular these are poor reasons to close a question.  In fact it seems that the people who code stackoverflow have changed the options in an attempt to stop this.

Comment: @CandiedOrange just because you assert that the burden of proof is on me, doesn't mean it is. You've seen yourself how the community responds to those questions, the burden is on you to prove that this is a bad thing (hint: it isn't). Furthermore, you apparently didn't read the tour page because the sentence I quoted ends with _show your work_ in brackets. And even Shog in his answer says that the question should be closed, just with _unlcear_ and not _too broad_. If his opinion isn't enough, John Atwood (SE founder) also repeatedly said that those questions are crap, look it up on meta.SE.

Comment: I always use "Unclear" for this.  As in, "I need to do XYZ."  "So, what's the problem? *(this is where the question is unclear)*  Go do it, and when you have an actual problem, come back to us."

Answer (score -3):

> However, there is nothing about it that seems too broad to me.

...then closing it as "Too Broad" would be lying. Are you OK with that? Lying? Not just to the person who *asked* the question, mind you; to those who might answer, those who might have the same question, others reviewing and the system itself (which uses question closure as input for various other things).

Do you consider yourself a *liar*, sir?

If not, then using this close reason in places where it does not apply is not for you.

I'm of the opinion that [*effort* is generally a poor reason to close questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange-in-general-be-awarding-as-for-effor), although lack of research is often a *great* reason to downvote. Homework tends to have other problems as well though: sadly, folks posting their homework verbatim often fail to actually write a question to go along with it, implicitly asking someone to solve a problem that's ill-defined to the satisfaction of someone (the person who assigned the problem) who will neither read it nor be able to clarify any ambiguities present. These can (and should) be closed as *unclear what you're asking*.

But in the absence of any other critical problems, questions that are well-specified, clearly-written and *about programming* should be left open.

Comment: Your edit just saved you from a snarky comment. The question in question is a straight up copypaste of a homework assignment that even failed to define the language; I personally don't care at all _how_ it is closed and deleted, just that it's reasonably fast. This was even one of the rarer cases where the question was closed before somebody could dump a heap of uncommented code as an "answer". On another note, is there a way to permaban the person that upvoted the question?

Comment: Who exactly is "you" here?  Shog9, could you please edit this answer to be a little less personal?

Comment: @CandiedOrange I think he refers to your note "nothing about it that seems too broad to me", meaning that one should use particular close reason only when one is certain that it applies

Comment: Bah, humbug.  If someone simply drops a spec on a question, the only true answer is "hire a developer."  That's off topic, as we have a site for doing so--one that you should be promoting.