# Is the "Too Broad" close reason applicable for zero-effort questions?

Tags: discussion

I was going through the **Reopen Votes** queue and came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47422899/lists-and-loops-and-changing-elements), which was closed as being *too broad*, with the following explanation:

> Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough
>   detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct
>   questions at once.

The question itself is a very basic python question, but, as far as I can tell, it's specific enough and does not lack in clarity. Corroborating that is the fact that there are three answers to this question that all seem sufficiently correct and concise.

I take stock of the options that are available to me:

- **Leave Closed:** taking into account that the trend on meta (see e.g. [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253069/whats-the-appropriate-new-current-close-reason-for-how-do-i-do-x/253096#253096)) seems to be that zero-effort questions deserve a down-vote, but not a close vote, and that we shouldn't [use close votes as super down-votes](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/a-close-vote-is-not-a-super-downvote), leaving the question closed doesn't seem to be the right choice. Maybe the question needs to be closed for a different reason (i.e. duplicate), but closing it as *too broad* feels like [lying](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288969/3558960).
- **Reopen:** if leaving it closed is not the right choice, then it should be reopened.
- **Edit and Reopen:** this seems to be even better than just reopening it. The title could indeed be a little bit more to the point, and there are a number of minor grammatical and other issues that could be addressed.
- **Skip:** the non-committal option. If no decision can be made for this type of question (of which there are thousands every day), why even bother  having a review queue at all?

So, trying to interpret the close reasons as precisely as I can, and taking into account what I find on meta, the correct option seems to be to **reopen** this question in one way or another.

However, having just failed an audit on a similar question that I voted to reopen, I decided to go for the **Leave Closed** option, and: lo and behold! I am promptly congratulated! It was just a test, it says, and I made the right choice so I passed.

So this leaves me feeling confused. Which is it? Do we have an implicit license to close zero-effort questions as being *too broad*, even if they don't fit the description of the close reason? Or, is it again time to revisit the close reasons? Or, should this question just be removed from the review queue?

---

**TL;DR**

Based on the current wordings of the close reasons, and the current stance on meta (don't close vote for a lack of problem-solving effort), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47422899/lists-and-loops-and-changing-elements) should not have been closed (unless someone had identified a duplicate).

However, it was closed as being *too broad* and shows up as an audit question in the **Reopen Votes** queue where the accepted action is **Leave Closed**.

Isn't that contradictory?

Comment: Can’t you think of many different answers and approaches to that problem? It seems to me intrinsically _too broad_, as there are too many possible solutions.

Comment: @DavyM So you're referring to a lack of definition effort, i.e. the asker did *not formulate a clear, specific question*?  How does that jive with the fact that within 10 minutes of asking three correct answers were formulated?

Comment: I still believe that that a question that can many possible correct answers can work as a signal that a question can be _too broad_... or even _opinion based_. The OP just wants answerers to produce code for them: there is not a clear problem statement, just a work assignment. There are too many different possible "correct" answers. Personally, I see no way a question like that should be left open.

Comment: If you can't see that the question was closed a month ago and got 4 DVs then following the advice of five other SO users is always best.  That *is* what audits check for, if you can't see this then failing an audit is a likely outcome.  If you have a reason to disagree then you have to look closer.  Notable is that this question already got rejected by the Triage queue at the time is was posted.  And is *still* around a month later stinking up the place, drawing 45 views.  Ugh, triage is one heck of a  waste of time.

Comment: @yivi Python is not my main focus, but as far as I can tell, there are only two generally acceptable correct answers: 1) a list comprehension; 2)  a more structured programming approach. Subtracting 9 from a value also seems to be pretty open-and-shut.

Comment: @HansPassant OK, to help with my understanding: you're saying that the question was closed for a justifiable reason. Which one of the close reasons would that be then?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/257887/17034

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Sorry I didn't get back to you last night. I was answering your main question, if "Too Broad" is the appropriate close reason. The appropriate reason to use "Too Broad" is generally for a lack of definition effort, if it doesn't already fall into one of the other categories. That is when the Too Broad reason is applicable to no-effort questions. The rest of your examples are important if we're asking "Well, how do we close this specific question then?" But that was not your question, and as the dup also covers, there are different ways to handle it depending on the situation.

Answer (score 3):

A few points to consider:

1. Voting involves humans, and is therefore imprecise.
2. The listed close reason is just the highest voted of the close reasons.
3. If you think a question should be closed, then you should not vote to reopen if the question is listed with what you think is the *wrong* close reason.
4. In the review queues, if you are not sure, click through and read the entire question/answers/comments in context.  And if still unsure, then skip.

**Is the “Too Broad” close reason applicable for zero-effort questions?**

No, as a blanket statement, it is not.  But it is often difficult to distinguish between "Unclear what you are asking" and "Too Broad".  In this particular case I would have voted to close as "Unclear what you are asking", but see point #1 above.  I certainly could be wrong.

To address the question at the end of your question:

***Which is it?***

1. *Do we have an implicit license to close zero-effort questions as being too broad, even if they don't fit  the description of the close reason?*
2. *Or, is it again time to revisit the close reasons?*
3. *Or, should this question just be removed from the review queue?*

I do not think the answer is option #1, because of points #1 and #2. I don't even want to weigh-in on option #2, so maybe it is that, but I don't think so. As for option #3, I think point #3 covers it, so no, it is not #3.

So, on this multiple choice, I would have to go with:

4. None of the above.

Comment: I'll take your advice and just skip next time, but I don't understand how this question would qualify as "unclear what you're asking". Both input, expected output, and the logic to be applied, are provided. As far as I can tell, none of the close reasons apply, unless someone ferrets out a duplicate.